# Can't get CLNDR.JS mini-calendar to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, calendar

After a while of experimenting with the clndr.js code to develop a working calendar for one of my websites, I stumbled upon a problem. I wanted to recreate the mini-calender (second one) that's on the [clndr.js-homepage](http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/) but just couldn't get it to work. 
It always showed a list of numbers (the days, 1 to 31) but not an actual calendar.

Could anyone help me with this one? It's probably an easy fix, but I'm just not that good at JSON to fix it myself.

Code that's in my `test.html` file: (→ has jquery.js / clndr.js / underscore.js / moment.js correctly linked)

```
<div id="mini-clndr">
      <script id="mini-clndr-template" type="text/template">

        <div class="controls">
          <div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo;</div><div class="month"><%= month %></div><div class="clndr-next-button">&rsaquo;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="days-container">
          <div class="days">
            <div class="headers">
              <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %><div class="day-header"><%= day %></div><% }); %>
            </div>
            <% _.each(days, function(day) { %><div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div><% }); %>
          </div>
          <div class="events">
            <div class="headers">
              <div class="x-button">x</div>
              <div class="event-header">EVENTS</div>
            </div>
            <div class="events-list">
              <% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
                <div class="event">
                  <a href="<%= event.url %>"><%= moment(event.date).format('MMMM Do') %>: <%= event.title %></a>
                </div>
              <% }); %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </script>
    </div>
```

Code that's in my `test.js` file: (linked with `<script src="test.js"></script>`)

```
var clndr = {};

$( function() {


  var currentMonth = moment().format('YYYY-MM');

  var events = [
    { date: currentMonth + '-' + '2', title: 'Test', location: 'New York' };

  clndr = $('#mini-clndr').clndr({
    template: $('#mini-clndr-template').html(),
    events: events,
    clickEvents: {
      click: function(target) {
        if(target.events.length) {
          var daysContainer = $('#mini-clndr').find('.days-container');
          daysContainer.toggleClass('show-events', true);
          $('#mini-clndr').find('.x-button').click( function() {
            daysContainer.toggleClass('show-events', false);
          });
        }
      }
    },
    adjacentDaysChangeMonth: true,
    forceSixRows: true
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Please check your markup includes all the supported files Mainly check these files full-clndr.less,mini-clndr.less,clndr-3.less,clndr-4.less in clndr.less

The supported files

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prism.css" />

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="js/jquery1.10.js"></script>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/clndr.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/clndr.less" />
<script src="js/jquery2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->

<script src="js/prism.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/clndr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>CLNDR.js</title>
```

the html body

```
  <div id="mini-clndr">
    <script id="mini-clndr-template" type="text/template">

        <div class="controls">
            <div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo;</div><div class="month"><%= month %></div><div class="clndr-next-button">&rsaquo;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="days-container">
            <div class="days">
                <div class="headers">
                    <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %><div class="day-header"><%= day %></div><% }); %>
                </div>
                <% _.each(days, function(day) { %><div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div><% }); %>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="headers">
                    <div class="x-button">x</div>
                    <div class="event-header">EVENTS</div>
                </div>
                <div class="events-list">
                    <% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
                    <div class="event">
                        <a href="<%= event.url %>"><%= moment(event.date).format('MMMM Do') %>: <%= event.title %></a>
                    </div>
                    <% }); %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </script>
</div>
```